# Gulp - sourcemaps aren't loading source in Chrome

Tags: gulp, source-maps, gulp-uglify

I haven't tested all browses but I use chrome regularly.

With Grunt I had no problem with uglify and the map file produced.  In Chrome, when in the developer tools, both the min.js and the original .js are loaded.

I'm trying to learn Gulp and after hours of trying I cannot get the map file to link the original .js to match the .min.js.

Here is my gulpfile.js.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
    , uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
    , rename = require('gulp-rename')
    , sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// default means this task will run whenever you type “gulp” at the command line without any parameters.
gulp.task('uglify:apps', function () {

    gulp.src(['core/apps/**/*.js', '!/**/*.min.js'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({ extname: ".min.js" }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('core/apps/'))
    ;

});


gulp.task('default', ['uglify:apps']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gulp-uglify` as of Jan 15 2014 does not have working sourcemaps built in.

This is the current solution for getting sourcemaps to work:

`npm install gulp-uglify@https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-uglify/tarball/sourcemap_fix --save-dev`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


gulp.task('ug', function(){
  gulp.src('./test.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./out'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['ug']);
```

Example repo: https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-test-sourcemaps

Comment: Thank you for jumping on this quickly and posting a repo.  I'll try out the solution.

Do you think gulp-uglify will fix this?  It seems like a glaring mistake.

Comment: @user3448990, Yes, there is a pull request from floridoo right now. I have poked on the issue to get some motion.

Comment: @user3448990 install 1.1.0, he merged the changes. issue fixed

Answer (score 1):

In my case I updated gulp-uglify and gulp-sourcemaps to: 
"gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.5",
"gulp-uglify": "3.0.2",

And I changed a little minification function
from:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '../' }))
```

to:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '.' }))
```

for some reason when `sourceRoot: '../'` I cant see sources in browser (but debugger; and breakpoints were stopping the execution, I just didnt see the code)

My whole code right now

```
function minifyJs(src, dest) {
var minifyPaths = [src];
return gulp.src(minifyPaths)
.pipe(domSrc.duplex({ selector: 'script[data-concat!="false"]', attribute: 'src', cwd: '../' })) //dont pay attantion here
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(babel({
    presets: ["es2015-script"],
    compact: false
}))
.pipe(concat(dest))
.pipe(gulp.dest("."))
.pipe(uglify({
    compress: {
        unused: false
    }
}))
.pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '.' }))
.pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

}